# Pandas data frame with time column

Tags: pandas, time

I have df with column with time like this:

```
time
12:30
12:15
12:00
```

I need to have it in float type like this:

```
time
12.5
12.25
12.00
```

I have tried:

```
df.time = df.time.replace(":", ".", regex=True).astype(float)
```

but I have unsatisfactory result, like this:

```
time
12.3
12.15
12.00
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [`pandas.to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) on a modified version of the input string (to match the expected format), then convert to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by 60:

```
df['time_float'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['time']).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

output:

```
    time  time_float
0  12:30       12.50
1  12:15       12.25
2  12:00       12.00
```

Alternative using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as you originally intended:

```
df['time'] = (df['time']
              .str.replace('(:)(\d+)',
                           lambda x: f'.{100*int(x.group(2))//60}',
                           regex=True)
              .astype(float)
              )
```

Comment: @ariac great, I also added an alternative with an optimized version of your original approach ;)

Comment: It was my mistake, I have no errors

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with append `:00` by [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html), then convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and last divide by `60`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].add(':00')).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
print (df)
0  12.50
1  12.25
2  12.00
```